# Simple copy paste function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, copy-paste

How I can make simple copy and paste for text in JavaScript? I would like to achieve that when I select some text in a `textarea`, then I can click on a button to copy it, then I can go to another page right click in another `textarea` and choose paste.

Comment: copy and paste text ; description : when a select some text in textArea , then click for a button to make copy it , when go to another page right click in textarea and choose paste .

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

You cannot access the clipboard in JavaScript, meaning flash is more or less your only option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function copy() {
 if(window.clipboardData) {
   window.clipboardData.clearData();
   window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById('txToCopy').value);
 } 
}

function paste() {
 if(window.clipboardData) {   
   document.getElementById('txToPaste').value = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
 } 
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:copy();">Copy</a>
<br />
<input type="text" name="txToCopy" id ="txToCopy"/>
<br /><br />
<a href="javascript:paste();">Paste</a>
<br />
<input type="text" name="txToPaste" id="txToPaste"/>
```

It's a simple copy and paste function. Its working well in IE.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you it's work done but i want work in all Browser  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to fetch user keyboard actions, you probably want to use Hotkeys: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way (and working in all browsers) is to watch keys pressed by user and if he press CTRL+C, save some data you want to copy into some variable.

I mean something like this:

```
    var myClipboardVariable;

    document.onkeyup = function(e){

        if ((e.key == 'c') && e.ctrlKey){
            // save data (you want to copy) into variable
            myClipboardVariable = ....//some data
        }

        if ((e.key == 'v') && e.ctrlKey){
            // paste saved data
            .... paste your data from variable myClipboardVariable
        }

    }
```

Comment: What if the user is on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard).

If you just want to copy user selected text you can do:

```
document.execCommand("copy");
```

if you need to select it previously:

```
document.getElementById('txToPaste').select();
```

- In my case this code didn't work - it turns out `select()` don't work for `disabled` inputs.
- you don't need any special permissions if you run it from an `onClick` event listener, if you want another event to trigger the copy you are a bit in trubbles.
- it works for me on Firefox and chrome, MDN says it won't work for safari but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClipBoard API for this,

```
//copy
navigator.clipboard.writeText("yuuhhhh");
//paste ,this needs user permission 
navigator.clipboard.readText()
```

Now you can use .then function to do what ever you want.