# Jquery bind copy issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to display whatever a user copies when using IE. Im using jquery and the following code:

```
$('#data').bind("copy", function(e) {alert(clipboardData.getData("text"));})
```

The problem is whenever I copy it shows the data previously copied. not the current data showing the function is called before the data is put on the clip board. is there any workaround

Comment: Copy/paste issues are complicated - IE is one of the few remaining browsers that allows you to do this.  Firefox straight up blocks this.  The proper workaround requires a Flash hack. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579232/simple-copy-paste-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @JohnStrickler  Thats what I found out too. Just wondering if this can be done anyhow through jquery.

Comment: @SNAG See my answer.. and let me know if that is what you want.

Comment: plugins like this could help to get it working: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to get the selected text. See below code to get the text selection,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BBycP/2/)

```
$('#data').bind("copy", function(e) {
    var selectedText;
    //reference post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/275825/297641
    // IE version
    if (document.selection != undefined) {
        $(this).focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    }
    // Mozilla version
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
        var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }

    alert(selectedText);
});
```

**Reference**:
[How to get selected text from textbox control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript)